# Why is the 2nd level of the pointers in a hash table not need malloc() to allocate memory?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-management, hash

I am currently learning separate chaining to resolve collisions in hashing.  Below shows an example that creates a hash table. I see `hash_tbl *new_table = malloc(sizeof(hash_tbl));` allocates a big chunk of memory for `new_table`.  Next, `new_table->list = malloc(sizeof(node *) * size);` ***seems to divide*** new_table by `size` to store the 1st level of pointer of `node **list`.

Q1: The part I can't figure out is that why I do NOT need to malloc() the 2nd level of the pointer at `node **list;` marked by ###?

Q2: Since the code is correct, does `for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    new_table->list[i] = NULL;  }` initialize the head pointer of the linked list pointed to by new_tbl->list[i]?

p.s. Could someone can illustrate his explanation graphically?

```
typedef struct Node {
    char *str;
    struct Node *next;
} node;

typedef struct Hash_Tbl {
    int size;       
    node **list; //### 
} hash_tbl;

int main() {
  int size = 6;
  create_hash_table(size);
}
hash_tbl *create_hash_table(int size) {
  if (size < 1)   return NULL;

  hash_tbl *new_table = malloc(sizeof(hash_tbl));
  if (new_table == NULL)    return NULL;

  new_table->list = malloc(sizeof(node *) * size);
  if (new_table->list == NULL)     return NULL;

  // Initialize the elements of the hash table
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    new_table->list[i] = NULL;
  }

  new_table->size = size;

  return new_table;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out is that why do I NOT need to malloc() the 2nd level of the pointer at `node **list`;

Since the hash table starts off empty, you do not need to allocate the 2nd level *yet*. The code of `create_hash_table` sets all buckets to `NULL` to indicate that they are empty.

> does [for loop] initialize the head pointer of the linked list pointed to be `new_tbl->list[i]`?

There isn't one "head pointer" in a hash table. Each element of the `list[]` array is a head pointer of its own. All these pointers are initialized to `NULL`, indicating that their corresponding bucket is empty.

Initially, all bucket lists are empty. When you start adding items to the hash table, the lists start filling in.

The diagram below shows a hash table with six buckets. Buckets 1 and 3 have some items; the remaining buckets are empty. Bucket 1 has no collisions, while bucket 3 has a two-way collision.

[image: Memory layout]

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight , thanks for your reply.  Does 
      new_table->list = malloc(sizeof(node *) * size); 
divide "the same memory space of new_table" by size to store the 1st level of pointers of node **list?

Comment: @PumpkinCake You can call them "1st level of pointers of `node **list`", but it's easier to think of them as list headers for the individual buckets. `malloc` does not "divide" the same memory space; all it does is giving it to you so that you could divide it using other means of the language. The specific thing that subdivides the space is the square bracket `[...]` operator. When you do `new_table->list[i]`, the operator knows to go `i` elements deep into the memory pointed to by `new_table->list`, thus "subdividing" it into individual pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> The part I can't figure out is that why do I NOT need to malloc() the 2nd level of the pointer at node **list; marked by ###?

The 2nd level of pointer will be allocated whenever required. This is just the initialization part and that is why we simply initialize it to NULL here.

> Since the code is correct, does for (int i=0; ilist[i] = NULL;  } initialize the head pointer of the linked list pointed to be new_tbl->list[i]?

Consider new_table->list as an array of pointers. With each element representing a chain of nodes. So, in a sense you are correct. Each element of this array could be a head to the respective chains/buckets you are going to form later on.